# SharePoint Date column - Format as dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM:ss

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

How can I format the SharePoint Date column to show value in this format: `dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM:ss`

I know that this can be done with JSON formatting but not sure what the right formatting is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use simpler version of above JSON code like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=toLocaleDateString(@currentField) + ' ' + toLocaleTimeString(@currentField)"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: You're right of course, I did try something like this too, but for some reason at the time it didn't work and I couldn't figure out why... Thanks for sending working JSON though :) That was bugging me! Simplified a little more in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following JSON formatting (`Column Settings > Format Column > Advanced`)

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "children": [
      {"elmType": "div", "txtContent": "=toLocaleDateString(@currentField)"},
      {"elmType": "div", "style": {"padding": "0 2px"}},
      {"elmType": "div", "txtContent": "=toLocaleTimeString(@currentField)"}
    ]
}
```

Ultimately this creates 3 elements per date. A div containing the local date format (dd/mm/yyyy) and a div containing the local time format (hh:mm:ss) with a final element in between providing some offset between date and time.